# Journey Builder Entry Event update is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

My web application is communicating with Salesforce Cloud databases.

In Exact target, I've created one Journey Builder with actions as created and updated.

When lead gets created in SFDC, Exact Target(ET) Journey Builder(JB) is syncing the lead data into ET Data Extension, up to here it is fine.

But when lead is updated in SFDC, ET is not syncing the updated lead data to ET Data Extension.

While creating the JB selected option as Created, Updated and some Meet specific criteria, when created it is syncing but update nothing is happening..

How to sync the updated data into ET Data extension?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to SF Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5

- Each time a record is created or updated, Salesforce evaluates the primary object rule criteria.
- If criteria are met when a new record is created, the rule runs.
- **When a record is updated, the rule runs only if the record meets rule criteria after the update. The rule does not run when a record that previously met rule criteria is updated**.

Comment: you are right, but here when updating the object in SFDC, it is not effecting in Exact target Data extension.